# "Object expected" with trying to make a time input on Javascript

Tags: javascript, time

The error is for
Line: 3
Char: 3

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
var timeEnd = setHours(17);
var timeStart = setHours(15);

if(n < timeEnd && n > timeStart){
  var r = confirm("Press a button");
  if (r == true) {
    x = "You pressed OK!";
    _system.shutDown();
  } else {
    x = "You pressed Cancel!";
    die;
  }
}
else {
  window.alert("This isn't the right time!")
}
```

If anyone can help me fix that problem and any other mistakes you see, that would be helpful.

Comment: Line 3, char 3 is `r` in `var`. I doubt there is an error there. Please read [ask].

Comment: Do you have a global function called `setHours`, or did you mean to call it on `d`?

Answer (score 2):

You need the variable `d` for the access of the date object.

```
var timeEnd = d.setHours(17);
//           ^^^
var timeStart = d.setHours(15);
//             ^^^
```

I suggest to change this line

```
var n = d.getHours();
```

to

```
var n = Date.now();
```

because this fits the other time values for comparison. [Date#now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now):

> The `Date.now()` method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

That corresponds with [Date#setHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) and makes it comparable:

> The `setHours()` method sets the hours for a specified date according to local time, and returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC until the time represented by the updated [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instance.

Comment: That suggestion doesn't make a lot of sense, `timeEnd` and `timeStart` are being set to undefined and you are setting the same object to two different hours.

Comment: @JuanMendes `setHours` returns a number (at least [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)).

Comment: @Biffen Yes, my bad, it's buried there. I skimmed it and assumed it returned undefined because there isn't a section for return value

Comment: @JuanMendes …but I do agree it's an odd way of doing things. But that's not what OP's question is about.

Comment: thank you! This helped alot.